# How can I do the work of Universal USB Installer from Linux?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive

I want to create a live USB for Linux Mint that is the same as, or comparable to, what would be done via the pendrivelinux.com Universal USB Installer on Windows, but done from Linux.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html

Comment: You will first have to clearly define in very specific terms exactly "*what would be done via the pendrivelinux.com Universal USB Installer on Windows*" entails.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you; please restate your comment as a response so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to create your own installer, just follow the standard media creation procedure at [Read the Docs.com](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html):

> **In Linux Mint**
>
> Right-click the ISO file and select *Make Bootable USB Stick*, or launch
> *Menu > Accessories > USB Image Writer*.
>
> Select your USB device and click *Write*.